# Jenkins: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings

Tags: jenkins, log4j, jira, slf4j, jira-plugin

I'm trying to run integration tests for a JIRA plugin in jenkins. I get the following warning:

```
Running xxx
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/prj/xxx/atlassian/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.6.4/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/prj/xxx/atlassian/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.6.4/slf4j-simple-1.6.4.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
```

Any idea how to disable this?

I have alrady read that: http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings

But this didn't help me too much.

What exactly dependency or exclusion (and where in the pom.xml) do I need to set to get rid of this warning.

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.xxx</groupId>
<artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>

<organization>
    <name>xxx</name>
    <url>xxx</url>
</organization>

<name>ClearQuestIdTrimmer</name>
<description>This plugin trims the ClearQuestIds.</description>
<packaging>atlassian-plugin</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jira.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Add dependency on jira-core if you want access to JIRA implementation classes as well as the sanctioned API. -->
    <!-- This is not normally recommended, but may be required eg when migrating a plugin originally developed against JIRA 4.x -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jira.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- WIRED TEST RUNNER DEPENDENCIES -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>atlassian-plugins-osgi-testrunner</artifactId>
        <version>${plugin.testrunner.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2-atlassian-1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Uncomment to use TestKit in your project. Details at https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/jira-testkit -->
    <!-- You can read more about TestKit at https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Plugin+Tutorial+-+Smarter+integration+testing+with+TestKit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-tests</artifactId>
        <version>${jira.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-func-tests</artifactId>
        <version>${jira.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jira-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${amps.version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <productDataPath>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/generated-test-resources.zip</productDataPath>
                <productVersion>${jira.version}</productVersion>
                <productDataVersion>${jira.version}</productDataVersion>
                <testGroups>
                    <testGroup>
                        <id>wired-integration</id>
                        <productIds>
                            <productId>jira</productId>
                        </productIds>
                        <includes>
                            <include>it/**/*WiredTest.java</include>
                        </includes>
                    </testGroup>
                    <testGroup>
                        <id>traditional-integration</id>
                        <productIds>
                            <productId>jira</productId>
                        </productIds>
                        <includes>
                            <include>it/**/*TrdTest.java</include>
                        </includes>
                    </testGroup>
                </testGroups>
                <!-- Uncomment to install TestKit backdoor in JIRA. -->
                <!--
                <pluginArtifacts>
                    <pluginArtifact>
                        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira.tests</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jira-testkit-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${testkit.version}</version>
                    </pluginArtifact>
                </pluginArtifacts>
                -->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<properties>
    <jira.version>6.1-20130626</jira.version>
    <amps.version>4.2.3</amps.version>
    <plugin.testrunner.version>1.1.1</plugin.testrunner.version>
    <!-- TestKit version 5.x for JIRA 5.x, 6.x for JIRA 6.x -->
    <testkit.version>6.0.25</testkit.version>

    <!-- Set encoding to UTF 8 - needed for Jenkins Integration Test -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <!-- run integration tests in headless mode on CI -->
    <xvfb.enable>true</xvfb.enable>
</properties>
```

Comment: Try this      
    mvn dependency:tree To know dependency tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Maven Dependency](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/index.html) plugin to trace the source of transitive dependencies:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=slf4j-simple
```

With that output, you should be able to add the needed exclusions in the pom.xml.

Comment: With mvn dependency:tree I could find the jar i don't need and exclude them with the <excluding> tag.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you don't have problem when running your maven build locally? If so, you can probably ignore this issue. If you do have the same problem locally then ignore what follows and use dependency:tree :)

The reason is that Jenkins bundle multiple slf4j bindings to work-around a fatal issue.

The commit log was

> Bundle slf4j binding to the war. See the comment in war/pom.xml for
>   detailed discussion. This is fundamentally a "damned if I do, damned
>   if I don't" situation, but given that JENKINS-12334 is a fatal error,
>   and the downside of bundling the binding jar is "multiple binding"
>   warning, it seems like the lesser evil is to bundle it and risk some
>   warnings.

[Issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-12446) | [Commit](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/commit/ef1ad6ca29c313fa0b4bc6f5dcd8344046221049) | [More information](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/ef1ad6ca29c313fa0b4bc6f5dcd8344046221049/war/pom.xml#L122)